# How can I start/stop as a service as a normal user without sudo

Tags: 16.04, permissions, services

I am installing my custom application on the Ubuntu machine. Now I want to start/stop my application as a service with normal user without sudo permission.

My application installation path:-

```
/usr/local/myapp
```

Note: My application will create some folder and files under /tmp for processing during the application run.

After I logged into the Ubuntu machine, I want to start like below command without using sudo

```
service myapp start
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Depends on what "myapp" is doing. If it is binding to a privileged port you need to use root. You would need to change to a higher unprivileged port. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182798/why-are-ports-below-1024-privileged . That is just a guess, we need more information about "myapp".

Answer (score 8):

Edit the sudoers file with `sudo visudo` and add a line

```
USER        ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service /usr/local/myapp *
```

Then you don't need to enter your password for this specific command.

Other possibility: Create a script that includes starting the service, set the `suid` bit for the script and make it be owned by root (`sudo chown root /usr/local/bin/startMyappService`).

Beware of security pitfalls! Such a file must not have write permissions to anybody! Use absolute paths. Always think twice what you are doing!

Comment: Although useful, I am not sure it answers the question. "Now I want to start/stop my application as a service with normal user without sudo permission." so hard to know if they want to run "myapp" without root privilges or if they just want to run sudo without a password.

Comment: Services are "system" programs so they need to be run as such. Are you just wanting to have a user's program communicating with another program pretending to be a service that is running in the background? If that's the case, the user can run the "service" as  $/usr/sbin/service &. However, this "service" will only communicate with this user as it doesn't have root permissions.

Comment: @jpezz: If the "service" doesn't need root permisson, the question doesn't make much sense to me, so I did suppose it needs. Meanwhile I suppose the OP isn't really interested in an answer and doesn't bother to read it or answer the comments.

Comment: @Philippos, I agree with you but I wanted to include the possibility that his definition of service was that of a system service rather than a background program interacting with a user's program.

Comment: remember you still need to do sudo:
"sudo service myapp start"